# '70s book series: Submarine entombed in iceberg for 400 years, England has a druidist-like worship, and an underground "ce-tee"

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find the name of a novel or series of books that were published in the 1970s.

The book started of with a submarine crashing into an iceberg and the crew being frozen for some 400 years. When they re-animate they find London a ruin and England reverted to some form of nature worship (like druidism). A number of the crew have different adventures and one party finds an underground 'ce-tee' that still has flying helicopters (or ornithopters).

I also recall there was a thing called by a strange name (which I can't remember) but translated as 'the mystery'. Turned out to be a submarine missile launch box that only someone with knowledge of its origins could open. Think it was opened and things ended with a bang...

Answer (score 4):

*[The Fires of Lan-Kern](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/t/peter-tremayne/fires-of-lankern.htm)* by Peter Tremayne

> Lan-Kern is a Celtic world equally of both the past and the future…The
>   crew of the nuclear submarine return from a Polar trip to find a
>   British landscape completely devoid of life. The disoriented crew
>   search in vain, only to find mutated animals and ruins. Then the
>   overworked nuclear drive explodes, leaving crew member and botanist
>   Frank Dryden alone in the forbidding world.  He is befriended by the
>   Celtic Tribe of Lan-Howlek, but soon drawn into their bloody battle
>   with the evil followers of the witch Nelferch and he must undergo the
>   painful and terrifying initiation rites of a Druidic healer, so that
>   he may search for the holy relic, An Kevryn, the secret key to the
>   Universe.